# Dealing with None values when using Pandas Groupby and Apply with a Function

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a `Dataframe` in `Pandas` with a letter and two dates as columns. I would like to calculate the business days between the two date columns for the previous row using `shift()`, provided that the `Letter` value is the same (using a `.groupby()`). I was doing this with `.apply()`. This worked until I passed in some data in which one of the dates was missing. I moved everything to a function to handle the missing value with a `try/except` clause, but now my function returns `NaN` for everything. It appears the `None` value for date is impacting each call of the function, whereas I would think it would only do it when the `Letter` from the `.groupby()` is `A`.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

def business_days(x):
    try:
      return pd.DataFrame(np.busday_count(x['First Date'].tolist(), x['Last Date'].tolist())).shift().reset_index(drop=True)
    except ValueError:
        return None

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A', datetime(2016, 1, 7), None],
                        ['A', datetime(2016, 3, 1), datetime(2016, 3, 8)],
                        ['B', datetime(2016, 5, 1), datetime(2016, 5, 10)],
                        ['B', datetime(2016, 6, 5), datetime(2016, 6, 7)]],
                  columns=['Letter', 'First Date', 'Last Date'])

df['First Date'] = df['First Date'].apply(lambda x: x.to_datetime().date())
df['Last Date'] = df['Last Date'].apply(lambda x: x.to_datetime().date())

df['Gap'] = df.groupby('Letter').apply(business_days)

print df
```

Actual Output:

```
  Letter  First Date   Last Date  Gap
0      A  2016-01-07         NaT  NaN
1      A  2016-03-01  2016-03-08  NaN
2      B  2016-05-01  2016-05-10  NaN
3      B  2016-06-05  2016-06-07  NaN
```

Desired Output:

```
  Letter   First Day    Last Day   Gap
0      A  2016-01-07         NAT  NAN
1      A  2016-03-01  2016-03-08  NAN
2      B  2016-05-01  2016-05-10  NAN
3      B  2016-06-05  2016-06-07  7
```

Comment: In your current code, if a Letter group has a single `NaT` in a single row, the busday_count function raises a ValueError and None is returned. Do you want the entire Letter group to have Gap values of NaN or do you wish to compute the business days for non-NaT rows?

Comment: @unutbu Just for the non-NaT rows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Ignoring the `NaT`s for the moment, note that the `np.busday_count` calculation
  can be done on whole columns of `df` *before* applying `groupby`. This will
  save time since this replaces many calls to `np.busday_count` (one for each
  group) with a single call to `np.busday_count`. One function call applied to a
  large array is generally faster than many function calls on small arrays.
- To handle the `NaT`s, you could use `pd.notnull` to identify the rows which
  have `NaT`s and mask the `First Date`s and `Last Date`s so that only valid
  dates are sent to `np.busday_count`. You can then fill in `NaN`s for those
  rows where the dates had `NaT`s.
- After we calculate all the business day counts, all we need to do is group by
  `Letter` and *shift* the values down by one. That can be done with
  `groupby/transform('shift')`.

---

```
import datetime as DT
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def business_days(start, end):
    mask = pd.notnull(start) & pd.notnull(end)
    start = start.values.astype('datetime64[D]')[mask]
    end = end.values.astype('datetime64[D]')[mask]
    result = np.empty(len(mask), dtype=float)
    result[mask] = np.busday_count(start, end)
    result[~mask] = np.nan
    return result

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A', DT.datetime(2016, 1, 7), None],
                        ['A', DT.datetime(2016, 3, 1), DT.datetime(2016, 3, 8)],
                        ['B', DT.datetime(2016, 5, 1), DT.datetime(2016, 5, 10)],
                        ['B', DT.datetime(2016, 6, 5), DT.datetime(2016, 6, 7)]],
                  columns=['Letter', 'First Date', 'Last Date'])

df['Gap'] = business_days(df['First Date'], df['Last Date'])
print(df)
#   Letter First Date  Last Date  Gap
# 0      A 2016-01-07        NaT  NaN
# 1      A 2016-03-01 2016-03-08  5.0
# 2      B 2016-05-01 2016-05-10  6.0
# 3      B 2016-06-05 2016-06-07  1.0

df['Gap'] = df.groupby('Letter')['Gap'].transform('shift')
print(df)
```

prints

```
  Letter First Date  Last Date  Gap
0      A 2016-01-07        NaT  NaN
1      A 2016-03-01 2016-03-08  NaN
2      B 2016-05-01 2016-05-10  NaN
3      B 2016-06-05 2016-06-07  6.0
```

Comment: I like applying the calculation to the whole column in one step. However, I get the value error, `ValueError: Cannot compute a business day count with a NaT (not-a-time) date`

Comment: Hm, I'm not able to reproduce that error. Do you get that when running the code I posted above?

Comment: If you are getting that ValueError on the code posted above, what is the version of Pandas and NumPy you are using? If you are only getting that ValueError when applying `business_days` to your own data (but not on the code above), what is the dtype of the arguments passed to `business_days`?

Comment: I'm also getting the same error as the user above. I'm using Pandas 0.19.2 and Numpy 1.11.3. `<ipython-input-118-70ecbc042cd4> in business_days(start, end)
      4     end = end.values.astype('datetime64[D]')[mask]
      5     result = np.empty(len(mask), dtype=float)
----> 6     result[mask] = np.busday_count(start, end)
      7     result[~mask] = np.nan
      8     return result
ValueError: Cannot compute a business day count with a NaT (not-a-time) date`

Comment: Okay, updating to Numpy 1.12.1 has resolved this issue.