# Setting values for a numpy ndarray using mask

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I want to calculate business days between two times, both of which contain null values, following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576552/dealing-with-none-values-when-using-pandas-groupby-and-apply-with-a-function) related to calculating business days.  I've identified that the way I'm setting values using a mask does not behave as expected.

I'm using python 2.7.11, pandas 0.18.1 and numpy 1.11.0. My slightly modified code:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def business_date_diff(start, end):
    mask = pd.notnull(start) & pd.notnull(end)
    start = start[mask]
    end = end[mask]
    start = start.values.astype('datetime64[D]')
    end = end.values.astype('datetime64[D]')
    result = np.empty(len(mask), dtype=float)
    result[mask] = np.busday_count(start, end)
    result[~mask] = np.nan
    return result
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't return the expected business day differences (instead I get a number of very near 0 floats).  When I check `np.busday_count(start, end)` the results look correct.

```
print start[0:5]
print end[0:5]
print np.busday_count(start, end)[0:5]

# ['2016-07-04' '2016-07-04' '2016-07-04' '2016-07-04' '2016-07-04']
# ['2016-07-05' '2016-07-05' '2016-07-05' '2016-07-06' '2016-07-06']
# [1 1 1 2 2]
```

But when I check the values for `results` the results do not make sense:

```
...
result = np.empty(len(mask), dtype=float)
result[mask] = np.busday_count(start, end)
result[~mask] = np.nan
print result

# [           nan               nan   1.43700866e-210   1.45159738e-210
# 1.45159738e-210   1.45159738e-210   1.45159738e-210   1.46618609e-210
# 1.45159738e-210   1.64491834e-210   1.45159738e-210   1.43700866e-210
# 1.43700866e-210   1.43700866e-210   1.43700866e-210   1.45159738e-210
# 1.43700866e-210   1.43700866e-210   1.43700866e-210   1.43700866e-210
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it a problem with the mask? `mask = pd.notnull(start) & pd.notnull(start)`
Not sure why you use `pd.notnull(start)` twice so maybe a bug.

Comment: ah! unfortunately this was a transcription typo not a typo in the code i was testing. good catch though.

Comment: How are `start` and `end` created?  I tried what you are trying to do and it seems to work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that with your version of numpy, you can't use a boolean array as an index to an array. Just use `np.where(mask==True)` instead of mask and `np.where(mask==False)` instead of ~mask, and it will work as desired.